# Как выгрузить (конвертировать) список 1С в excel таблицу (и наоборот)

Tags: excel, 1с

Есть такая таблица:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как выгрузить (конвертировать) список 1С в excel таблицу (и наоборот)?

Comment: Список из 1С сохранить можно средствами платформы. А что имеется в виду, когда из Excel в 1С?

Comment: через кнопку [ЕЩЕ] - Вывести список - Сохранить как XLSX